# Why does WHM / cPanel keep saying my password is weak and must be 65 strength at least?

Tags: domain, password, cpanel, whm

I've been trying to create my very first account on https://trycpanel.net/wwwacctform.html, but I've faced a weird error.
Basically, I want to set a password for my account. But, it keeps saying it's weak and must be at least 65 strength. Even though, I used auto-generate password and wrote a really strong one by myself, but nothing seems to work. All I get is this error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DS0df.png

Here is some methods I used, but none of them worked:

1. Used another browsers (Chrome, Opera, Firefox)
2. Refreshed the page
3. Rebooted my machine (Windows 10)

Any ideas why is this happening? Error code: `AJAX Error: Try Again`
Thanks in advance.

I also tried disabling the strength limit in the security settings, but it refuses my order and throw this error:

```
404: Show/Hide Details
URL (POST):
/json-api/setminimumpasswordstrengths
 Body:
api.version=1&default=0&passwd=&list=&virtual=&createacct=&cpaddons=&sshkey=&postgres=&mysql=
 Response:
content-length: 555
content-type: text/html
date: Sun, 13 Feb 2022 00:23:32 GMT
server: nginx/1.17.8
strict-transport-security: max-age=63072000

<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.17.8</center>
</body>
</html>
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely an issue to do with the password strength configuration.

You can change the configuration in:

`Security-> Security Center -> Password Strength Configuration`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @KIVOX. Unfortunately, I also tried that, but now I see this error when I want to set the password strength to 0. (I updated my, the error is included there).

Comment: @LiquiKal I believe this is on purpose as `trycpanel` is just a preview of the WHM/cPanel platform.

Comment: True, the website starts with `try`. Well, do you know other way how to certificate my domain to use it in Telegram?